# the quantity of elements which include levels

Tags: javascript

How to count top-level divs, which include 2 levels?
For example,

```
<div>
   <div>
   </div>
   <div>
   </div>
</div>
<div>
   <div>
   </div>
   <div>
   </div>
</div>
<div>
   <div>
   </div>
   <div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer must be 3.
Thanks for answer!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: no, this is by class, I need general

Comment: thanks changed, top-level divs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I got all the `children` from the top level (`document.body`) then filtered the ones that are `div` elements and have 2 or more children.

```js
const divs = [...document.body.children].filter(elm => elm.tagName == 'DIV' && elm.children.length > 1).length;

console.log(divs);
```

```html
<div>
   <div>
   </div>
   <div>
   </div>
</div>
<div>
   <div>
   </div>
   <div>
   </div>
</div>
<div>
   <div>
   </div>
   <div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the best answer, but I want to point out that ANY answer to this question is going to be a bad practice. To the OP - if you want your `<div>` elements to be distinct in some way, you really, REALLY should add a class (or unique IDs) to those elements and select by that instead of working around W3C selector API with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have a set a className attribute for all the top level div. So you should have something looking like this:

HTML

```
<div class="parentDiv">
   <div>
   </div>
   <div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="parentDiv">
   <div>
   </div>
   <div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="parentDiv">
   <div>
   </div>
   <div>
   </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
let x = document.querySelectorAll('.parentDiv');
console.log(x.length + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const allDivs = document.querySelectorAll('#range div');

// the "length" will give you the recurrent count for the query above.
console.log(allDivs.length)
```

```html
<div id="range">
  <div>
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, a "parent" selector still does not exist in CSS today, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector), but the following might help:

```js
// get "top" level divs:
const topDivs = document.querySelectorAll('body > div');
console.log([...topDivs].map(d=>d.childNodes[0].textContent.trim()));

// get "divs having at least one further div as a child":
const twoLvlDivs=new Set()
document.querySelectorAll('div>div').forEach(d=>twoLvlDivs.add(d.parentNode));
console.log([...twoLvlDivs].map(d=>d.childNodes[0].textContent.trim()));
```

```css
div {padding-left: 20px}
```

```html
<div>1
  <div>1.1</div>
  <div>1.2</div>
</div>
<div>2
  <div>2.1</div>
  <div>2.2
    <div>2.2.1</div>
    <div>2.2.2</div>
  </div>
  <div>2.3</div>
</div>
<div>3
  <div>3.1</div>
  <div>3.2</div>
</div>
```