# How to count how many 2 level entries was on the page?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have two level tag entry

```
<div>...<div>...</div>..</div>
```

How can I get to know how many of such tag entries was used on the page using document.querySelector()? Should I right something like this?

```
document.querySelectorAll('div > div')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [the quantity of elements which include levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66967983/the-quantity-of-elements-which-include-levels)

Comment: Its a different question, look more attentively please

Comment: I would recommend learning more about the selector api since you have multiple very closely related questions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_object_model/Locating_DOM_elements_using_selectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out how many, you just need to do

```js
document.querySelectorAll("div > div").length;
```

Thats it

Answer (score 0):

You asked this same question earlier today and got complete answers but didn't mark them.

[the quantity of elements which include levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66967983/the-quantity-of-elements-which-include-levels/66968367)

Comment: Its a different question